# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies - how to know exactly what can not be loaded?

Tags: c#

Running one application I receive such error:

```
C:\Program Files\P2CGate\sdk\samples\net\basic>nsend.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'cgate_net, Version=0.9.10.31381, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
 one of its dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.
   at send.Send.Main(String[] args)
```

The message is too generic, because I don't know exactly what can not be loaded. It seems `cgate_net` **is** loaded because I do see some details `Version=0.9.10.31381`.

So I guess some of `dependencies` can not be loaded, but which one exactly?

Without knowing what can not be loaded I do not know how can I fix this problem. Why C# doesn't print what exactly can not be loaded and how to obtain this information?

Comment: ... *or* one of it's dependencies.

Comment: These problems happens since windows 3.1 in C: don't know how the system couldn't say which dll it is looking for.

Comment: @FelicePollano: Fortunately the *system* can say that.  I agree it would be handy if the *Exception* would share that information so we don't have to fire up Fusion Log Viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an assembly or one of its dependencies fails to load, you can see more details by looking at the Fusion logs:

- [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx)

See also this related question:

- [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 4):

The [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is your friend here.

The fusion log viewer monitors attempts to resolve .NET assemblies and displays the attempts visually.  It will tell you which assembly could not be resolved and how it tried to resolve it.

Be sure and **run as Administrator** or it will silently just do nothing.